# How to find out which dependency is failing to load

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am getting the following error when trying to run a web application:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
    Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'Atalasoft.dotImage.AdvancedDocClean.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
```

I am running on Windows Server 2003 & .NET Framework 4.0.  The same binaries and dll's are running successfully on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server.

How can I find out which dependency is failing to load?

**Edit**

Fusion logging shows the following:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (4/11/2011 @ 2:37:42 PM) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
LOG: DisplayName = Atalasoft.dotImage.AdvancedDocClean
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: Atalasoft.dotImage.AdvancedDocClean | Domain ID: 4
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///K:/App/Prd/SEMS/asp/sems/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = K:\App\Prd\SEMS\asp\sems\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\sems\cd484e8d
LOG: Cache Base = C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\sems\cd484e8d
LOG: AppName = a29ce80f
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: K:\App\Prd\SEMS\asp\sems\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: \\?\C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/sems/cd484e8d/a29ce80f/Atalasoft.dotImage.AdvancedDocClean.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/sems/cd484e8d/a29ce80f/Atalasoft.dotImage.AdvancedDocClean/Atalasoft.dotImage.AdvancedDocClean.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///K:/App/Prd/SEMS/asp/sems/bin/Atalasoft.dotImage.AdvancedDocClean.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: K:\App\Prd\SEMS\asp\sems\bin\Atalasoft.dotImage.AdvancedDocClean.dll
LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Atalasoft.dotImage.AdvancedDocClean, Version=9.0.2.43320, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2b02b46f7326f73b
LOG: A partially-specified assembly bind succeeded from the application directory. Need to re-apply policy.
LOG: Using application configuration file: K:\App\Prd\SEMS\asp\sems\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: \\?\C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Atalasoft.dotImage.AdvancedDocClean, Version=9.0.2.43320, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2b02b46f7326f73b
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\sems\cd484e8d\a29ce80f\assembly\dl3\63ae24d2\b8096e5c_94f5cb01\Atalasoft.dotImage.AdvancedDocClean.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

**Edit**

Output from CppCodeProvider that failed to load

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (4/11/2011 @ 2:37:42 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
LOG: DisplayName = CppCodeProvider, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///K:/App/Prd/SEMS/asp/sems/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = K:\App\Prd\SEMS\asp\sems\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\sems\cd484e8d
LOG: Cache Base = C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\sems\cd484e8d
LOG: AppName = a29ce80f
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: K:\App\Prd\SEMS\asp\sems\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: \\?\C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: CppCodeProvider, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/sems/cd484e8d/a29ce80f/CppCodeProvider.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/sems/cd484e8d/a29ce80f/CppCodeProvider/CppCodeProvider.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///K:/App/Prd/SEMS/asp/sems/bin/CppCodeProvider.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///K:/App/Prd/SEMS/asp/sems/bin/CppCodeProvider/CppCodeProvider.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/sems/cd484e8d/a29ce80f/CppCodeProvider.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/sems/cd484e8d/a29ce80f/CppCodeProvider/CppCodeProvider.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///K:/App/Prd/SEMS/asp/sems/bin/CppCodeProvider.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///K:/App/Prd/SEMS/asp/sems/bin/CppCodeProvider/CppCodeProvider.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the dependency that seems to be missing is `Atalasoft.dotImage.AdvancedDocClean.DLL`.  When you run this on the 2008 machine, do you know from where this DLL is being loaded?  Do you have it locally deployed in the bin directory of the web app, or is it installed somewhere on that machine, or installed in the GAC?

Another thing to verify is that you're running the same version of .NET on both machines.  If the 2008 machine is running .NET 4, and the 2003 machine is not, you may not be loading the same DLLs.

A useful tool for debugging assembly loading problems is Fusion.  Fusion logging comes with .NET, you just need to enable it, and use the Fusion Log Viewer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I copied the Fusion Log Viewer from my PC to the server, started it on the server, changed the setting to Log All Binds to Disk, tried the web application and nothing seems to be logged.  All dll's are in the bin folder of the application on both servers.  Both servers are running .NET 4.

Comment: I forget, but you might need to enable a flag in the registry to turn on fusion logging.  I haven't done it for awhile, so I don't remember what exactly you need to do.

Comment: I had to set this registry key to get logging - Set the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\LogResourceBinds registry value to 1 (the value is a DWORD).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure then...  have you tried restarting the machine?  just a thought

Comment: After discovering that the CppCodeProvider was failing, I installed the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable and the problem was solved.

Comment: Not sure why Atalasoft doesn't tell you what components are required for deployment. They must assume everyone runs Visual C++ on their servers. ;-) C++ Runtime is required (2010 for .NET 4)

Answer (score 3):

I see a lot of reference to 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx

But remember that is .NET 1.1 version and it has the ASP.NET radio button. On the new fusion log you don't have the ASP.NET radio button.

I haven't seen the documentation on how to use the Fusion Log with ASP.NET. Registry key change is an option I see everywhere, but are there any documentation for version 4.0?

Does anyone know?

---

UPDATE : I found the solution here. I guess, I broke down and started working on the registry.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion

Add:

DWORD ForceLog set value to 1
DWORD LogFailures set value to 1

DWORD LogResourceBinds set value to 1

String LogPath set value to folder for logs ie) C:\FusionLog\

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out the documentation on Fusion logs here

- [Fusion Logs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Unfortunately the error could indicate an issue with dependencies of the dll you're trying to load, and if logging is enabled you should be able to see exactly which one this is.  Note that a dependency loaded into the loading application is not sufficient for giving a dll access to it in all cases (if they do not share the same application domain). I had some problems with this trying to make plugins with their own application domain at one point

Answer (score -1):

I think that means that it's DLL is not in your application's bin folder.  Try grabbing the assembly's DLL and manually placing it into that folder.

Comment: I can confirm that the dll is in the bin folder.  The exact copy of the folder works on a Windows 2008 server.  All assemblies are in the bin folder rather than the GAC