# Build error when converting website from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ocr

Project converted successfully, however when I build the website I get the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Atalasoft.dotImage.Ocr.GlyphReader.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

I do see the DLL in the BIN folder, which is where it is being referenced from, so one of the dependencies must be missing.

I turned on FusionLog viewer but I didn't see anything of use...

Comment: Do you have binding redirects for the assembly to a version that's compatible with .NET 4.0?

Comment: sounds like the current `.Dll` does not have any `.net 4.0` support  this could also be an issue with how you are referencing it as well `Locally  || GAC` here is something that someone reported on similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616673/how-to-find-out-which-dependency-is-failing-to-load you need to provide more information as to how you are referencing the .dll seeing it in the `Bin` folder is one thing actually `using as well as adding the reference` is another