# File Not Found Exception in my code

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, filenotfoundexception, assembly-resolution

In my Silverlight application, I have a map that I drag a GPX and TCX file onto and it populates the route on the map.

When I drag a GPX file onto the map it works, but when i do the same for TCX i get an error. Now if it is a GPX it will call different code than the TCX file.

**Here is the error:**

[image]
How do I understand what assembly it cannot load or what the real issue is? It's not giving me a lot of information.

Comment: Use the [fusion log viewer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2863911/547981).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616673/how-to-find-out-which-dependency-is-failing-to-load

Comment: @Jester I will look at this now, Thanks!

Comment: @skalinkin I will take a look at this question now thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Jester When i open up Fusion, set the Custom Log Path to a file on my computer and run my VS2010. Fusion does not find the application and also does not log anything?

Comment: Could be the same problem as described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1127431/113858 ?

Comment: I am still receiving this error. Any more suggestions?